# rvm install 1.9.2 Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

Installing RVM on Ubuntu 11.04.

Followed the instructions here: http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you

When it comes time to install Ruby, I get a permission denied exception.

```
kevinwmerritt@ubuntu:~$ rvm install 1.8.7
bash: /home/kevinwmerritt/.rvm/scripts/manage: Permission denied
```

The .rvm folder appears in my home directory and the bash scripts initialize rvm successfully.

Using sudo yields the following:

```
sudo rvm install 1.8.7
sudo: rvm: command not found
```

I am new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running into the same exact problem. I compared it against another installation of rvm on a different box that is working and noticed the permission for "manage" is different.

The box that is working:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 deployer deployer 59002 2011-05-19 22:56 manage
```

The box that is not working:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 deployer deployer 59076 2011-05-22 22:12 manage
```

I did a `chmod 755 manage` and that seems to have fixed it. I installed rvm the same way on both boxes, not sure why there's a difference.

You can try
`chmod 755 /home/kevinwmerritt/.rvm/scripts/manage` and see if that resolves it

Comment: Thanks Jhony for spelling it out for me! It looks like that did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If you did a single-user install of RVM do not use:

```
sudo rvm install 1.8.7
```

RVM creates its own sandbox in `~/.rvm` which does not need root privileges ever. At NO time do you need to use `sudo` before `rvm`. `sudo` will only screw up everything.

Use an unadorned `rvm install 1.8.7` or `rvm install 1.9.2` or any other version of Ruby known to RVM. You can see the list it knows about using `rvm list`.

Comment: I can confirm that using sudo with a single-user tended to never quite work. I made the effort to remove rvm and start from scratch, making sure to at no time use sudo. It made a massive difference and everything worked fine after that. Changing permissions didn't seem right.